# How to list all available brokers in Kafka cluster using Java API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, broker

What the title says.

Is there anyway (using Kafka Java API) to get the number of AVAILABLE Kafka brokers in a cluster?

I know that with the command line utility that comes with the Kafka server, this can be done; but I haven't found anything on how to do it using Java API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the broker's and cluster information from [kafkaAdminClient.describeCluster](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html)

> Get information about the nodes in the cluster, using the default options. This is a convenience method for #describeCluster(DescribeClusterOptions) with default options. See the overload for more details.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
properties.setProperty("client.id", "producerAdmin");
properties.setProperty("metadata.max.age.ms", "3000");
kafkaAdminClient = AdminClient.create(properties);

DescribeClusterResult result = kafkaAdminClient.describeCluster()
KafkaFuture<Collection<Node>> nodes = result.nodes();
```

And you can use [host](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/Node.html#host--),[port](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/Node.html#port--) methods in [Node](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/Node.html) class to get more information